# How to open program on client computer through RemoteApp on Windows Server 2008

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an winform application written in c# & it generates excel document & stores on user computer. After that it starts a process to open the excel file.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(dlgSave.FileName);
```

Till now the application was installed on individual user's computer. Now we are trying to distribute the app using [Remote App](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_RemoteApps_on_Windows_Server_2008_R2)

I am able to save the file on individual user's PC by accessing the folder using `tsclient`
Is there a way to automatically starting the excel application which opens up the stored excel file?

Comment: For your application to run on a server you need to things 1) The Same version of Net Library on deployed machine or you have to Publish Application and install on Server using the setup.exe that is generated when you publish 2) You need Microsoft Office Installed on Server.  Usually office is not installed on a server due to Licensing Requirments.  So if your application is using the Interop than the Runtime Interop need to be installed.  Usually the Interop gets installed when office is installed.

Comment: @jdweng I have already deployed the app on server & users are able to generate report. Earlier since the app was installed on their local machine, the excel report would open up automatically in Excel Office Application. Now since we don't have office installed on server, it can't be open. I am looking in some way we can open the file stored on user's local drive from remote app.

Comment: Excel should run on local client machine.  The app can either be installed on local machine or put on a common Network driver where app will fetch app from network drive or a  user environmental variables, or from the project configuration file.

Comment: MS Office is installed on individual user machine. How it can be started from remoteapp? System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(dlgSave.FileName); this doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Process class does not have any environmental variables like PATH.  When you start Excel it is usually from a shortcut that has the full path name of the executable.  When you are running a webpage that is located on a server you are actually downloading a html file to a browser on the client machine.The html was on a Server the code is running on the client machine.If you have an exe file on a server and you use your Windows explorer to double click on exe the exe is actually running on client machine not the server.Assume everything is running on client machine.Make sure your PATH are right.